# Python manually define matplotlib xlim()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to put an array of words in xlim( [ ] ) in place of a range of numbers. using normal python and matplotlib.

Like this:

```
ax.set_xlim(['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week4', 'week5', 'week6', 'week7', 'week8', 'week9', 'week10'])
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to set the `xticks`, not the `xlim`. See [here for an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`.  Something like:

```
# set the locations and labels of the xticks
plt.xticks( arange(10), ('week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week4', 'week5', 'week6', 'week7', 'week8', 'week9', 'week10') )
```

Where instead of `arange(10)`, you want an array of the x values of your data.